# C++ FindWindow to find current window

Tags: c++, windows, dll, findwindow

I have a program that opens a window (a video game, actually) on Windows 8.1. That program then calls an "extension" in the form of a  C++ .DLL that I compiled. Within that DLL, I need to get a handle to the window of the program (the video game) that is calling the DLL. I can do this using the FindWindow command combined with the name of the video game window. However, I sometimes need to have 2 copies of it open at once, both with the same window name. This means that using FindWindow(windowName) is not guaranteed to select the window that I actually want. Is there a way to get a handle to the window that is the same application that is calling the C++ code, without having to specify the name?

Comment: Why can't you just pass the window handle to the dll from the game?

Comment: The title of the post is confusing

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the title there. Should have proof read that first. I can't pass the window handle to the DLL from inside the game because the game uses a special scripting language that can call functions in external DLLs but can't call any standard language code from inside the game script itself.

Comment: @Jordan does the scripting language provide access to the window handle in any opaque way (w/o calling WinAPI), like, for example, Qt does? If so you could just pass it as a `void*` and cast it to `HWND`. If not, there is also a chance that the scripting language is executed inside the event loop of the application - if so, you can try calling `GetActiveWindow()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292(v=vs.85).aspx in the DLL, if it is called from the message loop it will get your window:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each window you get from `EnumWindow` that matches the `windowName` you can check `HWND's` process and pick one that belongs to the process you're running in. That can be done using [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx) function - it will give you the PID of the process the window belongs to and you can compare it to your own PID from [GetCurrentProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: How would you get multiple results with `FindWindow()`?

Comment: Indeed, I obviously meant EnumWindows (and possibly a check of title). I'll edit

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with the title - the OP simply used `FindWindow` before and was not aware you can't do what he wants with `FindWindow`.

Comment: Ok, so I went with this method to attempt a solution. I am able to grab the game window by iterating through EnumWindow and checking the classname with GetClassName(). However, the window has a different process ID than the "current process" does. In my last experiment, I was getting a WindowID = 20056 and a CurrentID = 9816. Maybe the game is running separate processes for display and code or something?

Comment: That might be the case but it is easy to check with ProcessExplorer, it has a function to find a process by window and also function of finding processes that loaded a specific DLL, see if you end up with the same process or not.

Comment: @AlexanderBalabin I just tried ProcessExplorer to check it out. GetCurrentProcessId is returning the expected ID that ProcessExplorer is showing the game as having. The ID that GetWindowThreadProcessId is returning for that window, though, doesn't even show up in ProcessExplorer. It's finding an ID that doesn't seem to exist...

Comment: @Jordan, are you looking at the return value of the GetWindowThreadProcesId or the output param? The return value is thread id of the window's thread and the process id is put into the last output parameter of the function.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. I was reading the return value of GetWindowThreadProcessId() instead of passing it a DWORD pointer. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [FindWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx) to enumerate all the windows with the given name (set `hwndParent` to `NULL` to use desktop as the parent and just pass the previous result as the `hwndChildAfter` when you search the second time, and so on) with [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetCurrentProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180(v=vs.85).aspx) to find out which of the windows belongs the the same thread you are being called from.

But then again - why not just pass the window handle to the dll directly?